# Traction object array

Tags: delphi

There is an array of 2 dynamic objects: Circle (SP) and a numbered inscription inside the object (LblPhoto).

Question: How do I determine which object in the SP [n] array is moved?

(SP[CurPhoto].OnTrack)

LblPhoto[n].position.y:=SP[n]position.x

```
var 
SP: array [0..10] of TSelectionPoint; // Circle
LblPhoto: array [0..10] of TLabel; // Text in Circle

// Add new circle
Procedure AddObjectPoint(X,Y:Single);
begin
  //
if CurPhoto>10 then
  begin
   ShowMessage('Maximum number exceeded ');
   exit;
  end;


        with dyn_frm do
         begin
             SP[CurPhoto]:=TSelectionPoint.Create(ImageViewer1); //
             SP[CurPhoto].Parent:=ImageViewer1;

             LblPhoto[CurPhoto]:=TLabel.Create(ImageViewer1); //
             LblPhoto[CurPhoto].Parent:=ImageViewer1;


            SP[CurPhoto].position.y:=y-120;
            SP[CurPhoto].position.x:= x;
            SP[CurPhoto].Width:=80;
            SP[CurPhoto].Scale.X:=6;
            SP[CurPhoto].Scale.Y:=6;
            SP[CurPhoto].OnClick:=PhotoDialogClick;
            SP[CurPhoto].OnTrack:=SelectionPoint1Track; /Fasten the object's handler


            LblPhoto[CurPhoto].Position.Y:=SP[CurPhoto].position.y-10;
            LblPhoto[CurPhoto].Position.X:=SP[CurPhoto].position.x-10;
            LblPhoto[CurPhoto].Text:=IntToStr(CurPhoto+1);


            Inc(CurPhoto);
         end;
end;



// Handler for moving the circle and moving the inscription inside
procedure dyn_frm.SelectionPoint1Track(Sender: TObject;
  var X, Y: Single);
begin
 LblPhoto[?].Position.X:=X-10;
 LblPhoto[?].Position.Y:=Y-10;
end;
```

Comment: Your post raises some questions, that affect a possible answer: How are the objects moved, by timer, mouse ...? Is there only one pair of objects being moved at any time?

Comment: We move object SP [n], and on event SP [CurPhoto]. OnTrack: = SelectionPoint1Track should change the position object LblPhoto [?]. Position.X: = X-10;
  LblPhoto [?]. Position.Y: = Y-10;

Comment: FYI, I have changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the question, the following may be a better solution:

Use the `Tag` property of `TSelectionPoint` to store the index of the array

```
SP[CurPhoto].tag := CurPhoto;
```

Then the `OnTrack` handler becomes

```
// Handler for moving the circle and moving the inscription inside
procedure dyn_frm.SelectionPoint1Track(Sender: TObject;
  var X, Y: Single);
begin
 LblPhoto[(Sender as TSelectionPoint).Tag].Position.X:=X-10;
 LblPhoto[(Sender as TSelectionPoint).Tag].Position.Y:=Y-10;
end;
```